# Namespacing issue in custom php package, unable to do "use joelwmale/RSSFeedPHP"

Tags: php, composer-php

I have created my own composer package but am having some issues trying to load and use it outside of the package itself (i.e in my laravel application).

My composer file looks like:

```
{
    "name": "joelwmale/rss-feed-php",
    "type": "library",
    "description": "RSS Feeds for PHP is a very small, lightweight, and easy-to-use library for consuming an RSS feed.",
    "keywords": [
        "rss", 
        "feed", 
        "php"
    ],
    "homepage": "https://github.com/joelwmale/rss-feed-php",
    "support": {
        "issues": "https://github.com/joelwmale/rss-feed-php/issues",
        "source": "https://github.com/joelwmale/rss-feed-php"
    },
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Joel Male",
            "email": "joel@joelmale.com",
            "homepage": "https://www.joelmale.com",
            "role": "Author"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1",
        "ext-simplexml": "*",
        "nesbot/carbon": "^1.26.3"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.5",
        "phpstan/phpstan": "^0.11.0@dev"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "RSSFeedPHP\\": "src/RSSFeedPHP/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": { 
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "test": [
            "@phpunit",
            "@phpcs"
        ],
        "phpunit": "vendor/bin/phpunit",
        "phpcs": "php-cs-fixer fix -v --diff --dry-run",
        "phpstan": "phpstan analyse --configuration phpstan.neon --level 3 src tests"
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "providers": [
                "RSSFeedPHP\\Laravel\\ServiceProvider"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

And my main class is located in: `src/RSSFeedPHP/RSSFeedPHP.php`. However, when I try and load it in my laravel application:

```
use joelwmale\RSSFeedPHP;
```

I get:

```
"Class 'joelwmale\RSSFeedPHP' not found"
```

Even though I have required it in my laravel application. I can see the joelwmale folder inside vendor, and can also see my package and it's composer file.

There has to be something wrong with the composer.json or way I've setup the project - but I can't figure it out.

Any ideas?

Edit: Repo link: https://github.com/joelwmale/rss-feed-php

Comment: Have you run `composer dump-autoload` and checked output?

Comment: I have, daly it just prints nothing other then "Dumping autoload" :(

Comment: I suggest you to read carefully about how PSR-4 works: https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/.

Comment: I do understand how it works. Your comment does not really help as I am already following PSR-4. I have even looked at Carbon's composer file (which works like `Carbon\Carbon` but for some reason that is not working for me. Right now I can get it working doing `use RSSFeedPHP\RSSFeedPHP`, but what I want to achieve is doing a `vendor/package` namespace, e.g: `use joelwmale\RSSFeedPHP`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "RSSFeedPHP\\": "src/RSSFeedPHP/"
    }
},
```

This registers your class under the `RSSFeedPHP` namespace. Anything in the *src/RSSFeedPHP/* directory can now be loaded as if it were in that namespace. Try using

`use RSSFeedPHP\RSSFeedPHP;`

Note that the name of your class must be `RSSFeedPHP` if your file is called *RSSFeedPHP.php*, and its namespace must thus be also `RSSFeedPHP`, i.e.

```
<?php

namespace RSSFeedPHP;

class RSSFeedPHP {}
```

Comment: How would i follow a typical `vendor/package` namespacing? I did have it `joelwmale/RSSFeedPHP` before, but then when using the namespace I needed to do: `use joelwmale/RSSFeedPHP/RSSFeedPHP` 

I simply want to be able to do: `use joelwmale/RSSFeedPHP` and it automatically load the class.

I have added my github repo to the original post sorry.

Comment: You can use any namespace you want. The name that ends up in the _/vendor_ directory is the one you specify under the `name` key in _composer.json_. E.g. if your package's `name` is `joelwmale/rssfeed` then you will see a directory _/vendor/joelwmale/rssfeed_. You can use any namespace in there, but it's good practice to choose a unique one for your packaging, like `Joelwmale`. Then you can issue `use Joelwmale/RSSFeedPHP;`, or `use Joelwmale/Feed/RSSFeed;` or whatever if you want to "sub"package.

Comment: Yep fully understood. If I wanted my namespacing to be `use joelwmale/RSSFeedPHP;` how would I achieve that with the composer.json in the file above? The issue ATM is that I can get that to work - but I'd have to do: `use joelwmale/RSSFeedPHP/RSSFeedPHP` to use the main class. I thought it was possible to somehow tell composer if no class is supplied, to then use that class.

So that doing: `use joelwmale/RSSFeedPHP` would automatically load the `RSSFeedPHP.php` file? and therefore the static methods accessible.

Comment: It would. If _RSSFeedPHP.php_ is located in _src/RSSFeedPHP_, and your composer says - under the `psr-4` key - `"RSSFeedPHP\\": "src/RSSFeedPHP/"`, then when you call `use RSSFeedPHP/RSSFeedPHP;`, it will load your class. So in order to change that namespace, change `"RSSFeedPHP\\": "src/RSSFeedPHP/"` to `"joelwmale\\": "src/RSSFeedPHP/"`, and you'll be able to call `use joelwmale\RSSFeedPHP;`.

Comment: Ah that makes total sense. Beautiful. thank you very much for your help!